# Celery - RabbitMQ - execution order

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

Im running some long tasks where I need to ensure that the queued tasks execute in order of reception.  What I've found in my first tests is that when I reach the max number of workers (CELERYD_CONCURRENCY), the following tasks that are sent are queued, and then the first of those to be executed is actually the latest one to be received.

Of course the opposite behavior is what Im after, that the oldest messages are the first to be executed when there is a free worker.

What is the explanation for this behavior and how can it be changed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This turned out to be a result of the Rabbitmq setting prefetchCount, which prefetches a set of messages per channel.

Since I am using the queue for long-running tasks, I solved the problem by setting [CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#std%3asetting-CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER) to 1, which is by default 4, so that only one message is prefetched and so the execution order is preserved.